# Stable app using Fusion Tables suddenly getting 503 server error

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Since about 14 hours ago my users have started reporting problems that they are not able to save their data in Google Fusion Tables using my app.

I have used Fusion Tables in my Android app for a number of years and typically generate around 2,000 Fusion Table requests daily.  This is well inside my quota (and I checked this morning to make sure I was not generating over usage issues).

As of last night I am receiving problem reports from users that indicates they cannot save any data.  Authentication and reading of existing tables is working fine.

Running the app under debug I am seeing a 503 error from the server when the app tries to post data to a Fusion Table.  The actual exception appears as follows (I've edited the specific table and access token):

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   https://www.googleapis.com/upload/fusiontables/v1/tables/xxxxxx/import?access_token=xxxxxxx

The app is trying to POST csv data.  Here is a sample request body:

0,"931 NE Linden Ave 97030","Gresham, OR 97030","-122.4238587,45.5041952,0"
1,"1941 Southeast Paloma Drive, Gresham, OR 97080, USA","1941 Southeast Paloma Drive, Gresham, OR 97080, USA, null","-122.392526,45.48251,0"
2,"21801-21823 Northeast Halsey Street, Fairview, OR 97024, USA","21801-21823 Northeast Halsey Street, Fairview, OR 97024, USA, null","-122.4381921,45.5343266,0"

As the app has been working absolutely fine for months (and I've not made any changes to my Fusion Table code for at least a year) I'm assuming the Fusion Tables team rolled out a change last night but I can't find any notification that something was going to happen.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

One of the internal services we use had a spate of errors related to uploading around the time you had your problem. We're looking into the cause, but at the moment it appears to be OK.